# How to get an image and a string array form a single Web Api Get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two Web API get methods. One gets an image and the other a string array. The question is, for the sake of reducing payload and/or traffic, how can I get both, an image and a string array from a single Web API2 Get method in C#.

Comment: you can convert the image to a base64 string representation and pass it along with the string array.  `{ "stringArray"  : ["a", "b", "c"], "image"  : "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlh....hAAOw===" }`  draw back is that the bigger the image the bigger the payload to return. the client would need to be able to interpret the string representation of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the image to a base64 string representation like a [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

```
data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>
```

and pass it along with the string array.

```
{ 
    "stringArray"  : ["a", "b", "c"], 
    "imageData"  : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...kJggg==" 
}
```

one of the drawbacks is that base64 encoding makes file sizes roughly 33% larger than their original binary representations, which means more data down the wire.

The client would need to be able to interpret/parse the string representation of the image.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Comment: My whole intention is to reduce payload and/or traffic. I could include the link for the image in the string array and have the client use that to get the image. However, I am trying to find a way to not even add that to the communication. Thank you Nkosi.

Comment: The `intention to reduce payload and/or traffic` would have been some good information to include in your question. Without the complete picture, those trying to help you will have to guess your intentions.

Comment: If the 33% image data increase is unacceptable, you might be able to reverse the process.  Convert the array in to binary data and send it in the binary response stream along with the binary image data.  It would be trickier to parse and make use of the result on the client-side, but it could save significant data if the image is large and the array is small.